# How to compile torch 1.5.0 without GPU support?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pip, pytorch

I want to install pytorch 1.5.0 on AWS lambda. Since the torch library is very large, I need to make it as small as possible to fit within the size limits. My script looks like this so far:

```sh
    mkdir python
    docker run \
        --rm \
        -v $(pwd):/build \
        python:3.8 \
        sh -c "
            cd /build;
            pip3 install torch==1.5.0 -t python/torch --no-cache-dir;
            find . -type d -name '__pycache__' | xargs rm -rf;
            find . -type d -name 'tests' | xargs rm -rf;
            find . -type f -name '*.py[co]' | xargs rm -rf;
        ";

    zip -r9 torch.zip python;
```

But the resulting zip file is very large (500+ MB). However, one of the largest files in the installation package is `libtorch_cuda.so`. Removing that file makes the zip file less than half the size. I know that cuda is a library for GPUs, and since AWS lambda doesn't have a GPU, i don't need this support. But when I remove that file torch will not `import` correctly.

torch 1.4.0, by comparison, is much smaller because it did not by default include the cuda libraries.

I want torch 1.5.0 without the GPU support.

Is there a way to pip install `torch==1.5.0` *without* gpu support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyTorch also distributes CPU only versions, that you can install with pip. Although they aren't published to PyPI, so you need to get them from their own registry.

You can get the CPU version on [PyTorch - Getting Started Locally](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) by selecting CUDA: *None*.

```sh
pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, what does the `+` mean in the pip install? Is that a standard syntax?

Comment: That's how pip separates additional arguments from the package names. For example if you want to install a package from a GitHub repo (not the already packaged version, but from the code), you would specify it as `git+https://github.com/user/repo`. There again the `+` separates the two, so it's a standard syntax of pip.

Comment: By the way, the pip install you gave, along with the pip install from the official website didn't work. But when I used the nightly cpu version it installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there's a CPU only install of Pytorch. You can also make the library smaller by removing files for testing and other non-essential applications (libtorch, caffe2, etc).

For AWS Lambda, the best way to deploy Pytorch is to create a special Lambda layer with your dependencies. Lambda layers have a size limit of 500 MB, compared to 250 MB for your deployment. Your model size also contributes to the limit. You should have your actual model file in your Lambda deployment, while your dependencies (Pytorch) should be in a Lambda layer.

Also remember you don't "install" anything on Lambda. You create a package that is loaded every time your function is invoked. For this reason, large deployments will have cold start issues. It's not unreasonable to expect 10-20 seconds of latency for a cold start. You can get around this by creating another deployment that pings your lambda function every few minutes to keep it hot. This can get tricky though if you need multiple functions available concurrently.

The best way to deploy your model on Lambda would be to convert your model to a protobuf file using ONNX or Torchscript so you can run the model without needing the full Pytorch library.